# Rails migration issue with PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have created a migration to add a column named `blurb` to a table with only one other column called `full_name`. After I run my migrations, this new column appears to be added when I check from the database console of postgresql database, but not from the Rails app console. Then after a period of time, it vanishes from the postgresql console as well.

I don't know how to account for this. My migration was created using the rails migration generator and it's a :text field.

```
class AddBlurbToPeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :people, :blurb, :text
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :people, :blurb
  end
end
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: PostgreSQL version number is 9.0.4

Comment: What are you doing during this "period of time"? Are your dev/production/test databases all different?

Comment: I am literally doing nothing. I am testing this in the development environment and all environments are on a different database.

Comment: What is the exact sequence of events? Stop server, run migrations, check `\d` in `psql`, ...

Comment: Correction: actually I should add that I am restarting the Rails console in that period of time, and I think the column is getting lost right after the console gets loaded. (I verified this by querying the schema on postgresql console as the Rails console was starting.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to run reload! on console after "rake db:migrate". Or simply restart console.

Comment: Wow! `reload!` worked. I am amazed. My question is why did _that_ work? It's weird that a column in the database would disappear by itself unless you restart the console...